# Unwanted request headers leading to a bad response

Tags: rest, http-headers, openai-api, azure-openai

I'm calling the openai api like so:

```
const response = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization:
        "Bearer ...,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      model: "...",
      prompt: promptString,
    }),
  });
```

but my the request in my browser(copied as fetch) is something like

```
fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "authorization": "....",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not.A/Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"114\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"114\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site"
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer",
  "body": "...",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

This makes for a bad completion from openai; copying this as cURL with the headers yields a similar result. I'm running this script via a chrome extension if that's relevant.

I'm unable to understand the cause of these headers and how I can prevent them. Any insight would be appreciated. Likewise any insight on the cause of the bad completion would be appreciated as well!

Edit:
I tried running this on nodejs for some similar results
My code:

```
openai
    .createCompletion({
      model: `text-curie-001`,
    //   temperature: 0.1,
    //   top_p: 0,
    //   logprobs: 2,
      prompt:
        prompt,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

The headers here are:

```
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "OpenAI/NodeJS/3.3.0",
    Authorization: "...",
    "Content-Length": 145,
```

I'd speculate that it's due to the `Content-Length` which gets added automatically.
Using fetch instead of the opeai package doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

those headers do not cause bad completion. those are security related headers automatically added by the browser. Since they are automatically added by the browser, you do not see them on node environment. you can read [all of those headers here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site)

the reason for bad response is you either did not pass an explanatory `promptString` or you choose a wrong model for your purpose. you can check the [purpose of differerent models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/overview)